# How to select items from json response c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am try to create a wild card search feature.
I have a json response it contains the username. i have to search the user like te*, so it will display corresponding usernames.
LIke test1, test2
The below code i am using to get the response

```
 var JSONResponse = await SendGraphRequest("/users/", null, null, HttpMethod.Get);
```

i have tried below code and trying to filter in graph only

i have try to filter in graph only

```
  var JSON = await SendGraphRequest("/users/", $"$filter=startswith(givenname,'b')", null, HttpMethod.Get);
                var graphUserResponse2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphUserResponseMapping>(JSON);
```

so instead of given name i want to try to filter using user name.

i am using newtonsoft to parse the json but it is difficult to get the username in list then then i will apply the wild card search. but the problem is how to get the username and store in a list?

The below is json response

```
{
   "odata.metadata": "test",
   "odata.nextLink":"test",
   "value": [
      {
      "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
      "objectType": "User",
      "signInNames": [
                {
                  "type": "emailAddress",
                  "value": "test1@gmail"
                },
                {
                  "type": "username",
                  "value": "Test1"
                }
        ],
    "personId": "1"
    },
    {
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
         "objectType": "User",
        "signInNames": [
            {
            "type": "emailAddress",
            "value": "test2@gmail.com"
             },
             {
              "type": "username",
              "value": "Test2"
              }
          ],
        "personId": "2"
        }
        ]
 }
```

TIA

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Roger!

You can use a Class ex:

YourClassName.cs

code inside this class

```
    public class SignInName
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "odata.type")]
    public string OdataType { get; set; }
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    public List<SignInName> SignInNames { get; set; }
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
}

public class YourClassName
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "odata.metadata")]
    public string OdataMetadata { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "odata.nextLink")]
    public string OdataNextLink { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Value { get; set; }
}
```

So you can search for the usernames and put it into a list.

Ex:

```
           List<string> userNameList = new List<string>();

        var json = "{ \"odata.metadata\": \"test\", \"odata.nextLink\":\"test\", \"value\": [ { \"odata.type\": \"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User\", \"objectType\": \"User\", \"signInNames\": [ { \"type\": \"emailAddress\", \"value\": \"test1@gmail\" }, { \"type\": \"username\", \"value\": \"Test1\" } ], \"personId\": \"1\" }, { \"odata.type\": \"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User\", \"objectType\": \"User\", \"signInNames\": [ { \"type\": \"emailAddress\", \"value\": \"test2@gmail.com\" }, { \"type\": \"username\", \"value\": \"Test2\" } ], \"personId\": \"2\" } ] }";

        var yourClassName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClassName>(json);

        foreach (var value in yourClassName.Value)
        {
            userNameList.AddRange(value.SignInNames.Where(x => x.Type == "username").Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
        }
```